# Cartesian product of two vectors in Julia

Tags: julia, cartesian-product

I have two vectors `x` and `y`, of respective lengths n and p. Is there a built-in way to create a np x 2 matrix which would be

```
x[1] y[1]
x[1] y[2]
...
x[1] y[p]
x[2] y[1]
...
x[n] y[p]
```

I can do that with a nested for loop, but I'm looking for a built-in function, if it exists.

Comment: Does anyone know how to modify the answer would be if I wanted by a n by p matrix of ordered pairs, where entry i j is (x[i], y[j])

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Julia is usually very fast in nested loops, so if the they are working correctly for you, you should proabably check the performance maybe just stick with it.

Other option would be using repmat (this one is a little faster than using repeat):

```
[repmat(x,1,length(y))'[:] repmat(y,length(x),1)[:]]
```

Did some quick testing of both methods:

```
x=rand(1000)
y=rand(1000)

function withrepeat(x,y)
    [repeat(x, inner=[size(y,1)]) repeat(y, outer=[size(x,1)])]
end

function withrepmat(x,y)
    [repmat(x,1,length(y))'[:] repmat(y,length(x),1)[:]]
end

withrepeat(x,y)
elapsed time: 0.21556302 seconds (95986112 bytes allocated)

with repmat(x,y)
elapsed time: 0.075604488 seconds (56000560 bytes allocated)
```

Not sure why so much difference and I think there is room for improvement still.
Haven't tried the product function inside the Iterators.jl package.

Also a little bit more information here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/dtl--SyFgwY

Hope this helps.

Tried a couple of nested loops and indeed is faster:

```
function withloops (x,y)
    leny=length(y)
    lenx=length(x)
    m=leny*lenx
    OUT = zeros(Float64, m,2)
    c=1
    for i = 1:lenx
        for j = 1:leny
            OUT[c,1] = x[i]
            OUT[c,2] = y[j]
            c+=1
        end
    end 
    return OUT
end
```

And, for the same `rand(1000)` for `x` and `y`.

```
withloops(x,y)
elapsed time: 0.011350679 seconds (16000128 bytes allocated)
```

Comment: Does `@inbounds` help the `for` loop?

Comment: @rickhg12hs It should yes, I was in a little rush when I posted it, so I didn't have time to test it properly, but I will do it tomorrow and edit the post accordingly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I tried using `@inbounds` but didn't get any noticeable improvement, maybe this is because there are no operations with the arrays and I'm just assigning values? Also, in my computer using vectors of length 10000 as input for `x` and `y`, produced memory errors when using `repeat` or `repmat` but worked fine with the nested loops function.

Answer (score 18):

At least in Julia 1.3, there is a built-in function Iterators.product, so
`Iterators.product(a, b) |> collect` should do the trick.

Comment: Note that `Iterators` is part of Julia's `Base` module (`Base.Iterators`), so you don't have to call `import` or `using` at all to be able to use `Iterators.product`.

Answer (score 12):

This is provided in the IterTools module (which replaces Iterators module).

Taken from https://github.com/JuliaCollections/IterTools.jl

> Iterate over all combinations in the cartesian product of the inputs.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> using IterTools
> for p in product(1:3,1:2)
>     @show p
> end
>
> p = (1,1)
> p = (2,1)
> p = (3,1)
> p = (1,2)
> p = (2,2)
> p = (3,2)
> ```

Comment: I'm not sure it replaces the Iterators module, because when using IterTools.product in julia 1.3rc4, it says it is deprecated in favour of Iterators.product

Comment: This solution worked much faster for my using Julia 1.5

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I might do it:

```
julia> x = [1, 2, 3, 4];

julia> y = [9, 8, 7];

julia> [repeat(x, inner=[size(y,1)]) repeat(y, outer=[size(x,1)])]
12x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  9
 1  8
 1  7
 2  9
 2  8
 2  7
 3  9
 3  8
 3  7
 4  9
 4  8
 4  7
```

you may also want to take a look at [Iterators.j](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Iterators.jl) -- specifically the `product` function.

Comment: Note that you can omit the brackets around the `inner` and `outer` arguments, so the formula reduces to `[repeat(x, inner=size(y,1)) repeat(y, outer=size(x,1))]`